# Some ping fails

Tags: router, ping

What can cause this? 192.168.0.222 is router what computer connected is.

[image]

Comment: You should check the logs contained on the router.  Of course 8.8.8.8 ( Google ) can't reach ( 192.168.0.122 ) for obvious reasons.  What command you specifically issued isn't all that clear.

Comment: It looks like you are showing more than one ping at once. note that the icmp_seq is not correctly ordered, and that the command says 100% of the 17 packets sent received a response (0% packet loss).